# Having problems with structs and pointers (incompatible pointer type)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, command-line, compiler-errors

```
struct sentenceTree {
    char *key;
    int duplicate;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
};

struct sentenceTree * Insert(struct sentenceTree *node,char *data) //Line 72
{
    if(node==NULL)
    {
        struct sentenceTree *tempNode;
        tempNode = (struct sentenceTree *)malloc(sizeof(struct sentenceTree));
        tempNode -> key = data;
        tempNode -> left = tempNode -> right = NULL;
        tempNode -> duplicate = 0;
        return tempNode;
    }

    if(compareStringsWithCapitals(data, node -> key) == 1)
    {
        node->right = Insert(node->right,data); //Line 86
    }
    else if(compareStringsWithCapitals(data, node -> key) == -1)
    {
        node->left = Insert(node->left,data); //Line 90
    }
    /* Else there is nothing to do as the data is already in the tree. */
    node -> duplicate++;
    return node;
}
```

When I run the make file for my program I get this error in my output:

```
rm      -f      bstsort
cc      bstsort.c       -o      bstsort
bstsort.c: In function ‘Insert’:
bstsort.c:86: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘Insert’ from incompatible pointer type
bstsort.c:72: note: expected ‘struct sentenceTree *’ but argument is of type ‘struct Node *’
bstsort.c:86: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
bstsort.c:90: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘Insert’ from incompatible pointer type
bstsort.c:72: note: expected ‘struct sentenceTree *’ but argument is of type ‘struct Node *’
bstsort.c:90: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

I have tried everything I could think of, and even a few solutions from the Stack Overflow website but I keep getting the same error. I am terrible with pointers and structs (new to C in general) so this is probably a very simple mistake that I am overlooking. Sorry if the question has already been answered before.

Comment: `Insert(node->right,data);` returns `struct sentenceTree *`.  `right` is a `struct Node *`  Why do you expect `node->right = Insert(node->right,data);` to work?  Suggest posting `struct Node` definition.

Comment: Where us Node defined?  Error is clear.

Comment: My mistake I forgot to edit the code, that was older, give me a second to update!

Comment: The `struct Node` that your `left` and `right` pointers point to is unrelated to `struct sentenceTree`.  As long as you're consistent, you shouldn't have problems.  Note that in C, the arrow `->` and dot `.` operators bind very tightly and should never have spaces around them.  (Syntactically, spaces are legal; the conventional coding style never uses that licence to add spaces.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Node should be a subtree, otherwise you can't recurse on it (as the compiler is telling you), so your definition should look like that:

```
struct sentenceTree {
    char *key;
    int duplicate;
    struct sentenceTree *left;
    struct sentenceTree *right;
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I messed up, didn't notice I didn't change the syntax from Node to sentenceTree......I guess that's what happens when you go 48 hours with no sleep -_- Anyway thank you for the answer.